# Why does this dotnet test run crash only in a Docker container?

Tags: docker, nunit, .net-core

I have this .NET Core 1.1 solution including an ASP.NET Core project and an NUnit test project. Each of projects has the necessary properties (I can show more if necessary).

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>1.1.1</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I can restore, build, and run the test suite locally (Windows 10) without any problems.

```
$ dotnet restore
Restoring packages for...
Restore completed in...
Generating MSBuild file...

$ dotnet build
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.3.409.57025 for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Example -> ...
  Test -> ...

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed ...

$ cd test/

$ dotnet test
Build started, please wait...
Build completed.

Test run for ...
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 15.3.0-preview-20170628-02
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Starting test execution, please wait...
NUnit Adapter 3.8.0.0: Test execution started
Running all tests in ...
NUnit3TestExecutor converted 11 of 11 NUnit test cases

Total tests: 11. Passed: 11. Failed: 0. Skipped: 0.
Test Run Succeeded.
Test execution time: ...
```

The test suite uses NUnit 3 and I'm on all the latest stable versions. Here are the interesting package refs.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.3.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.DotNet.InternalAbstractions" Version="1.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" Version="5.2.3" />
<PackageReference Include="FluentAssertions" Version="4.19.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost" Version="1.1.3" />
<PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.8.1" />
<PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.8.0" />
```

However, when I run the tests from a .NET Core SDK Docker image/container, they fail dramatically!

> The active test run was aborted. Reason: Unable to communicate with test host process.

Here's the simple Dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:1.1-sdk
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
```

The restore and build work find, but the test aborts!

```
$ docker image build --tag example:latest .
...
$ docker container run --rm -it example:latest
root@abcdef12345:/app# dotnet restore
...
root@abcdef12345:/app# dotnet build
...
root@abcdef12345:/app# cd test/
root@abcdef12345:/app# dotnet test
...
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 15.0.0.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Starting test execution, please wait...
NUnit Adapter 3.8.0.0: Test execution started
Running all tests in ...
NUnit3TestExecutor converted 11 of 11 NUnit test cases
The active test run was aborted. Reason: Unable to communicate with test host process.
```

Searches for this error message get me nowhere. I'm not sure how to debug a test run abort. Higher levels of verbosity do not print anything useful. Let me know what I can try to get more information, eliminate possibilities, and provide more useful info!

Comment: I created a `csproj` targeting `netcoreapp1.1` and added the `PackageReference`s you mentioned and it already fails on `dotnet restore` with:

    error NU1202: Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.2.3 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1). Package  Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.2.3 supports:
    error NU1202:   - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
    error NU1202:   - portable-net45+netcore45+wp8+wp81+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=wp8+netcore45+net45+wp81+wpa81)

Perhaps you are running a test project that targets the full framework?